# Mongoose Boolean default false

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema with a boolean field which I want to have a default value of `false`. My first guess how to do that was like that:

```
active: { type: Boolean, default: false }
```

But for some reason mongoose is always setting the field to `true`.

What can I do to change that?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Looks like you are missing something. setting `default: false` for that field will auto set it to false.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const projectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    isUsed: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }
});

mongoose.model('Project', projectSchema, 'project');
```